# Calculate VA for a given wattage

Tags: voltage, amperage, watts

How to calculate VA given a wattage say for example 300 watts.

Comment: Form factor? Did you mean power factor?

Comment: yes correct. Im not much of an electronic guy sorry for the mistake

Comment: What is a 'Stabilizer'? What do you mean by 'form factor'?

Comment: I mean a Voltage Stabilizer. Its a mistake with Form factor Its Power Factor

Comment: You can edit the question to fix it, before it gets closed as unclear.

Comment: Is the question still unclear ??

Comment: Now it's simple. You know the power. To calculate the VA rating, you also need  to know the power factor. The calculation is easily found online.

Comment: Yes it is still unclear. It is like asking for the temperature in your bathroom given your furnace in the basement burns 2000 l oil per year.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks.. suggest a website to calculate the power factor

Comment: Start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$VA = \frac{Watts}{PF}$$

where VA = volt-amps, and PF = power factor.

You'll have to find the power factor for the device yourself as you have given so little information.